# Make listview start intent after filtering text

Tags: android, listview

I am working on a app where I filter text from a `EditText` box and then show the "result" in a `ListView`. All the filtering works fine,but I am not able to start an intent from the "results" after filtering. Are there any way of referring to the text inside the  *list.add("The text here");* and then start an activity from it independent of its position in the `ListView`? Here is the code for the filtering:

```
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                getModel());
         setListAdapter(adapter);
        EditText filterEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filterText);
        filterEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

            }

            @Override

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }

        });

    }

    private List<String> getModel() {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("Example 1");
        list.add("Example 2");
        list.add("Example 3");

return list;
```